# FOREACH within a FOREACH in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have the following in a controller :

```
outputmodel.Add(new SP_RESULTS.RS_Plans()
{
  id = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput["id"]),
  name = Convert.ToString(SPOutput["name"]),
  code = Convert.ToString(SPOutput["code"]),
  from = Convert.ToDateTime(SPOutput["from"]),
  to = Convert.ToDateTime(SPOutput["to"]),
  days = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput["days"]),
  type_id = convert.YoString(SPOutput["type_id"]),
  package = Convert.ToString(SPOutput["package"]),
  day = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput["day"]),
  charge = SPOutput["charge"] as decimal?,
  type = Convert.ToString(SPOutput["type"]),
  percentage= SPOutput["percentage"] as decimal?,
  taxes = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput["taxes"]),
  order = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput["order"]),
  level = SPOutput["level"] as decimal?,
  Column15 = Convert.ToDecimal(SPOutput[15]),
  type_order = (SPOutput["type_order"]) as decimal?,
  adults = SPOutput["adults"] as decimal?,
});

var order = outputmodel.OrderBy(c => c.from);
ViewData["RS_Output"] = order;
```

grabbing output from an MS SQL stored procedure and storing in a viewdata (ordered by the FROM date).

My HTML has the following line to start to build the table

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["RS_Output"] as Enumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.RS_Plans>)
{
//basic <tr> <td> </td> </tr> table setup, using @item.variablename to pull info from the viewdata.
}
```

The output I am trying to achieve is for every TYPE under CODE, where the from date => current date, list the room type /package name etc.

and the output I am getting is

[image]

what I am trying to get is

[image]

What I think I need is a foreach after the current foreach, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out in my head.
I've changed the

var order line in my controller to now read

`var order = outputmodel.OrderBy(c => c.rate);`

..and I've put the HTML table create code in an if loop

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["RS_Output"] as Enumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.RS_Plans>)
{
if (item.to >= DateTime.now)
{
//basic <tr> <td> </td> </tr> table setup, using @item.variablename to pull info from the viewdata.
}
}
```

.. but, as I say, I am stumped.

I think I need another foreach within the newly created if loop, but I cannot figure out how.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["RS_Output"] as Enumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS.RS_Plans>)
{
if (item.to >= DateTime.now)
{
//other table headers/data

     <tr>
         <td>
             @item.type
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
            Room Type
        </td>
        <td>
            Package / Service
        </td>
        <td>
            Availablility
        </td>
        <td>
            Charge
        </td>
        <td>
            PAX
        </td>
        <td>
            Level
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
  ==>     @foreach (subitem = item.type)
  ==>        {
  ==>        foreach (item.type)
  ==>        {
        <td>
            @item.type_id
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.package 
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Column15
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.charge
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.adults
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.level
        </td>
  ==>           }
  ==>           }
     </tr>


}
}
```

can someone please advise?

thanks

### UPDATE:

Hi, what I found worked was, if I create a variable called string previous_type =" " , and another called  decimal previous_id =0 ,  then, in the view, I can amend with

```
if (item.to >= item.checkdate)
  {
  if ((previous_id != item.id) && (previous_type != item.type.ToString()) )
    {
     //some more code
  if (item.type.ToString().Equals(previous_type) == false)
  {
      previous_type = item.type.ToString();
      previous_date_from = item.date_from;
   }
    //etc
   }
```

Thanks everyone for their help

Comment: You probably need to remove that `@` from that foreach - you are already have it in the loop above

Comment: `foreach (subitem = item.type)` and `foreach (item.type)` won't compile. You need to write all of your C# code in C#. What does "every TYPE under CODE" mean? Are you saying you expect there to be multiple rows where code == "FOO", with each row having a different type? Do you want to group the rows by code? Or just order by code?

Comment: Hi @ed , yes, I understand it won't compile, it's just how i saw it working in my head. I'll amend my OP.

Comment: It's not fantastically clear what you want - I would start by using strongly typed views rather than ViewData/ViewBag.  I would also put the table header declaration stuff outside the foreach as you don't want that for every record.  Finally if you want to filter the data to only records > today, then do that in the controller - don't add filtering/sorting/etc. logic in the view if you can avoid it as it's far easier to just have display logic there....

Answer (score 0):

OK, I *think* what you want is to first group the data, then show a table which then shows 'sub-tables' for each *type* of accomodation?

if so, then yes you can do this with nested foreach loops, but you'd still be better off strongly typing your view and doing the grouping stuff in the controller (or possibly better in some sort of service layer so it can be more easily tested/re-used)...  but to get you started, something like this:

Models:

```
//Raw data
public class DataRowModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Class{ get;set;}
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime BookingDate { get; set; }
}

//Grouped data
public class GroupedDataRowModel
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DataRowModel> Rows { get; set; }
}

//View model
public class DataRowsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GroupedDataRowModel> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult TestData()
{
    var PretendDatabaseCall = new List<DataRowModel>
    {
        new DataRowModel{
            Id =1,
            BookingDate =new DateTime(2017,1,1),
            Description ="Booking 1",
            Class="Room"
        },
        new DataRowModel{
            Id =2,
            BookingDate =new DateTime(2017,2,1),
            Description ="Booking 2",
            Class="Room"
        },
        new DataRowModel{
            Id =3,
            BookingDate =new DateTime(2017,3,1),
            Description ="Booking 3",
            Class="Suite"
        },
        new DataRowModel{
            Id =4,
            BookingDate =new DateTime(2017,4,1),
            Description ="Booking 4",
            Class="Room"
        },
    };

    //We can now get the data from the database.  We want to group by class so we can
    //get a summary of items by class rather than a big flat list.  Most LINQ to SQL implementations
    //(e.g. Entity Framework) when working with Raw entities could convert this to SQL so the SQL server
    //does the grouping, but if not it can happen in memory (get all records, then standard LINQ does it on
    //the complete list)
    var dataGroupedByClass = PretendDatabaseCall
        //Minor Edit: apply filtering here not in the view!
        .Where(x=>x.BookingDate >= Datetime.Now)
        //Group by class.
        .GroupBy(x => x.Class)
        //for each class, get the records.
        .Select(grpItem => new GroupedDataRowModel()
        {
            //'key' is the thing grouped by (class)
            Class = grpItem.Key,
            //grpItem has all the rows within it accessible still.
            Rows = grpItem.Select(thisRow => thisRow)
        });

    var model = new DataRowsViewModel
    {
        Results = dataGroupedByClass
    };

    return View("~/Views/Home/TestData.cshtml", model);

}
```

And View:

```
@* Strongly typed view.  saves any casting back and forth.*@
@model SimpleWeb.Models.DataRowsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestData";
}

<h2>TestData</h2>


<table>

    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var groupEntry in Model.Results)
        {
            @*Add single row with just the class...*@
            <tr><td>@groupEntry.Class</td></tr>
            @*Header row for each class of booking*@
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var row in groupEntry.Rows)
            {
                @*add new row for each actual row*@
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @row.Id
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @row.Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @row.BookingDate
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </tbody>

</table>
```

This produces Data like I think you want:

```
Room
Id  Description Date
1   Booking 1   01/01/2017 00:00:00
2   Booking 2   01/02/2017 00:00:00
4   Booking 4   01/04/2017 00:00:00
Suite
Id  Description Date
3   Booking 3   01/03/2017 00:00:00
```

Obviously you want the 'Room' and 'Suite' parts to contain more information, but this should hopefully help get you started?